# Can I separate JsonConvert objects?

Tags: c#, .net, json, attributes, json.net

I have the following code that has FIRST and LAST name only. The DeserializeObject is looking for FIRST MIDDLE LAST. So John Smith would show, but not John P Smith. Is there a way to look for just first and last name?

```
#region Fields
private string firstName;
private string middleInitial;
private string lastName;
#endregion

#region Properties
public string FirstName
{
    get { return firstName; }
    set { firstName = value; }
}
public string MiddleInitial
{
    get { return middleInitial; }
    set { middleInitial = value; }
}
public string LastName
{
    get { return lastName; }
    set { lastName = value; }
}
#endregion

#region Constructors
public NamedIndividual()
{

}

var namedIndividual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NamedIndividual>(cov.GetAttribute("individual").Value);
```

Comment: can you paste how NamedIndividual is declared..

Comment: inside of your empty constructor can you just overload that or set the properties you are looking for there.. otherwise from the looks of it ..it looks like all 3 properties will get set.. does this make sense

Comment: it does... Thanks! So does that mean this is not really a question? Should I just delete?

Comment: you don't have too but you could vote up .and perhaps some other user may find this useful if they run into the same issue.. use the this.construct inside the constructor this.lastname this.firstname do you follow what I am saying ?

Comment: When you ask is there a way for FIRST and LAST to show, what do you mean?  Do you just want to have only FIRST and LAST deserialize, or do you want MIDDLE to be optional?

Comment: Good questions as well David.. I didn't consider that question to him as well since he was mentioning that he wanted first and last.. but your point is very valid

Comment: Yea, I would like to have FIRST and LAST and MIDDLE optional

Comment: @user54197, if you're using JSON.NET (which it looks like), then you can take advantage of `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes, as my example shows, to mark properties as optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.NET has a nice way of allowing you to mark properties as not required - you can use `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [DataContract]
    public class NamedIndividual
    {
        #region Fields
        private string firstName;
        private string middleInitial;
        private string lastName;
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
        public string MiddleInitial
        {
            get { return middleInitial; }
            set { middleInitial = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        public NamedIndividual()
        {

        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "{'FirstName':'David', 'MiddleInitial':'Q', 'LastName':'Hoerster'}";
            string name1 = "{'FirstName':'David', 'LastName':'Hoerster'}";

            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NamedIndividual>(name);
            var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NamedIndividual>(name1);

            Console.WriteLine(obj.MiddleInitial);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",obj1.FirstName, obj1.MiddleInitial, obj1.LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I mark `MiddleInitial` as an optional property - so my JSON string can contain it or not.  If I mark a property as required (`IsRequired=true`), then my JSON string better have the property or an exception will be thrown.

**UPDATE**  I may have implied that you need to use `DataContract` attributes in order to make some properties as not required or not.  JSON.net has their own set of attributes, too, and along with @L.B.'s comment below, not using any attributes provides the default behavior which is nothing is required.  Here's a quick example of using the `JsonObject` attributes:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class NamedIndividual1
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name2 = "{'FirstName':'David', 'LastName':'Hoerster'}";

        var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NamedIndividual>(name2);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", obj2.FirstName, obj2.MiddleInitial, obj2.LastName);
    }
}
```

(I could also not use any attributes for everything to be optional.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the default behavior (when you don't specify the attribute)?

Comment: What would I loose if I didn't use any `DataMember` other that an exception for "must" properties. It could easily be checked by `if(obj.FirstName==null)` which is much faster.

Comment: @svick default behavior, for a class declared with a `DataContract` attribute, is to hide the members unless they have a `DataMember` attribute applied.  Similar to WCF services.

Comment: @L.B If you only applied `DataMember` to "required" properties, then only those properties would be valid.  I believe if you don't apply a `DataMember` then that property won't be deserialized.  You would probably have to write your own converter.

Comment: @DavidHoerster, JsonConvert doesn't need any `DataContract` or `DataMember` attribute. It doesn't simply set any value to a property/field (this behaviour is changeable) if  not found in the json string.

Comment: @DavidHoerster A minimal example `public class A
    {
        public int I = 0;
        public int J = 0;
    } var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>("{I:666}");`

Comment: @L.B I didn't mean to imply that you needed `DataContract` attributes.  To be honest, that's how I've used it since we do a lot with WCF services and reuse our `DataContracts` for JSON serialization.  I'll update my answer to show a not required property.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

you could alter the Constructor or kepp it as an empty Constructor and create and overloaded Constructor

```
public NamedIndividual() 
{
  //empty Constructor
} 
//overloaded constructor
public NamedIndividual(string first, string last)
{
  this.firstname = first;
  this.lastname = last;
} 
 // or pass in the middle as an option
```